# T-SQL join query using distinct values from second table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I know this question might sound like a duplicate, but I've been through every question I could find; though it's still possible it might be a duplicate of a question I might have missed.

I have what at surface value appears to be a trivial requirement but no matter how I script it out there's always some caveat that's just not working.  I've tried `GROUP`, `DISTINCT`, `JOIN`, aggregate functions, etc.

Scenario:
`PRIMARYTABLE` contains a set of campaigns and `SECONDARYTABLE` contains the dates on which campaigns were run.  There can be multiple runs per campaign and I've included a `SUBKEY` for each run.

Requirement:
I need to be able to get the most recently run campaigns into a list so the user can more easily select from the campaigns that get run the most frequent.

```
PRIMARYTABLE
KEYCOLUMN   INFOCOLUMN
100000      Test 1
100001      Test Campaign
100002      Test Image 2
100003      Test Img
100004      Image Test
100005      Test
100006      Test Image 3
100007      Test Image 4
100008      Test Image 5
100009      Image Comparison Test 2
100010      Testing
100011      Test Fields
100012      Test 5
100013      test

SECONDARYTABLE
KEYCOLUMN   SUBKEY  DATECOLUMN
100000      100000  2017-06-02 04:09:57.593
100001      100001  2017-06-19 12:09:54.093
100001      100002  2017-06-27 10:51:14.140
100004      100003  2017-06-27 12:33:47.747
100006      100004  2017-06-28 10:29:53.387
100007      100005  2017-06-28 10:36:23.710
100008      100006  2017-06-29 22:31:03.790
100009      100007  2017-06-29 23:07:52.870
100009      100010  2017-10-04 16:05:40.583
100009      100011  2017-10-04 16:09:55.470
100011      100008  2017-09-08 14:02:28.017
100012      100009  2017-09-11 16:17:23.870
100013      100012  2017-11-07 16:55:55.403
100013      100013  2017-11-08 15:37:16.430
```

Below is somewhat of an idea of more or less what I'm after.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( a.[INFOCOLUMN] )
FROM [PRIMARYTABLE] a
INNER JOIN [SECONDARYTABLE] b ON ( a.[KEYCOLUMN] = b.[KEYCOLUMN] )
ORDER BY a.[DATECOLUMN]
```

Here's hoping for a Homer Simpson "Doh!" moment once I see how it's supposed to be done.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `the most recently run campaigns` >> use row_number() over(.. order by ... DESC)
2. `that get run the most frequent` >> use count(*) over(partition by ..)

Using window functions `row_number() over()` and `count() over()` enables selection by row of data that is "most recent" and ordering by "most frequent". Note that the DESCending order of dates brings about "recent" = 1.

```
select
       p.*, s.*
from PRIMARYTABLE p
inner join (
      select KEYCOLUMN, SUBKEY, DATECOLUMN
           , row_number() over(partition by KEYCOLUMN order by DATECOLUMN DESC) recent
           , count(*) over(partition by KEYCOLUMN) frequency
      from SECONDARYTABLE
      ) s on p.KEYCOLUMN = s.KEYCOLUMN  and s.recent = 1
order by s.frequency DESC, p.INFOCOLUMN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @PRIMARYTABLE TABLE
(
    [KEYCOLUMN] INT 
   ,[INFOCOLUMN] VARCHAR(24)
);

DECLARE @SECONDARYTABLE TABLE
(
    [KEYCOLUMN] INT 
   ,[SUBKEY] INT
   ,[DATECOLUMN] DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @PRIMARYTABLE ([KEYCOLUMN], [INFOCOLUMN])
VALUES (100000, 'Test 1')
      ,(100001, 'Test Campaign')
      ,(100002, 'Test Image 2')
      ,(100003, 'Test Img')
      ,(100004, 'Image Test')
      ,(100005, 'Test')
      ,(100006, 'Test Image 3')
      ,(100007, 'Test Image 4')
      ,(100008, 'Test Image 5')
      ,(100009, 'Image Comparison Test 2')
      ,(100010, 'Testing')
      ,(100011, 'Test Fields')
      ,(100012, 'Test 5')
      ,(100013, 'test');

INSERT INTO @SECONDARYTABLE ([KEYCOLUMN], [SUBKEY], [DATECOLUMN])
VALUES (100000, 100000, '2017-06-02 04:09:57.593')
      ,(100001, 100001, '2017-06-19 12:09:54.093')
      ,(100001, 100002, '2017-06-27 10:51:14.140')
      ,(100004, 100003, '2017-06-27 12:33:47.747')
      ,(100006, 100004, '2017-06-28 10:29:53.387')
      ,(100007, 100005, '2017-06-28 10:36:23.710')
      ,(100008, 100006, '2017-06-29 22:31:03.790')
      ,(100009, 100007, '2017-06-29 23:07:52.870')
      ,(100009, 100010, '2017-10-04 16:05:40.583')
      ,(100009, 100011, '2017-10-04 16:09:55.470')
      ,(100011, 100008, '2017-09-08 14:02:28.017')
      ,(100012, 100009, '2017-09-11 16:17:23.870')
      ,(100013, 100012, '2017-11-07 16:55:55.403')
      ,(100013, 100013, '2017-11-08 15:37:16.430');


SELECT a.[INFOCOLUMN] 
      ,b.[DATECOLUMN]
FROM @PRIMARYTABLE A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [DATECOLUMN]
    FROM @SECONDARYTABLE  B
    WHERE A.[KEYCOLUMN] = B.[KEYCOLUMN]
    ORDER BY [DATECOLUMN] DESC
) b;
```

It will give you the last execution of each campaign. You can filter then by date or ORDER BY and get TOP N from the final query.

Or you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT A.[INFOCOLUMN]
          ,B.[DATECOLUMN]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[KEYCOLUMN] ORDER BY B.[KEYCOLUMN]) AS [RowID]
    FROM @PRIMARYTABLE A
    INNER JOIN @SECONDARYTABLE B
        ON A.[KEYCOLUMN] = B.[KEYCOLUMN]
)
SELECT [INFOCOLUMN]
      ,[DATECOLUMN]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [RowID] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will return the list of campaigns in most frequent order of use. Note campaigns never run wont appear in your list. in this case you will to do a left join

```
SELECT a.[INFOCOLUMN] 
FROM   [PRIMARYTABLE] a 
 /* left */ JOIN [SECONDARYTABLE] b ON a.[KEYCOLUMN] = b.[KEYCOLUMN] 
group BY a.[infocolumn]
order by max(datecolumn) desc
```

here is a stub i did to test it

```
select 10000 id,'Campain A' cname into #a1 union all
select 10002,'Campain B' union all
select 10004,'Campain C' union all
select 10009,'Campain E' 

select 10000 id,'20170101' thedate into #a2 union all
select 10000,'20170102' union all
select 10009,'20170103' union all
select 10002,'20170104' union all
select 10004,'20170105' union all
select 10000,'20170201' union all
select 10000,'20170302' union all
select 10009,'20170403' union all
select 10002,'20170104' union all
select 10004,'20170205' union all
select 10000,'20170101' union all
select 10004,'20170302' union all
select 10000,'20170103' union all
select 10002,'20170404' union all
select 10002,'20170105' 

select #a1.cname
 from #a1 join #a2 on #a1.id = #a2.id 
 group by #a1.cname
 order by max(thedate) desc
```